# Enable USB debugging on Android remotely

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I've got the LG P970 phone running on Gingerbread with a broken screen. By broken screen i mean that screen displays nothing - it's lighten up, all black with color lines but it's touch sensitive (i believe). I've got important data on it and I want to get it back. Unfortunately USB debugging mode is disabled on the phone so `adb devices` command on linux shows empty dialog.

So here comes my question: is there any possibility to remotely turn on usb debugging mode on android device?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the contents of the external and/or internal memory (if that still works) on a PC ? Otherwize, Chromecast is a nice option, but I don't know how it's enabled. And no, the USB debugging is ONLY manually turned on/off.

Comment: You could try something like Droid@Screen (http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/) to display the screen of your device on your PC and see what you are doing (as long as touch works still).

Comment: @ashatte: Droid@Screen uses the debugging connection, so this will not work. However, if the device has some sort of video out connection (direct HDMI, MHL support, SlimPort support, etc.), that would be another possibility.

Comment: If there were a way to enable ADB remotely, it would be very insecure.

Comment: So you are one of the reasons I have to develop for Gingerbread still. Let this be a lesson, and update your phone! Gingerbread should be dead by now.

Answer (score 18):

This is how I solved this problem (on a Samsung Galaxy S4):

*This assumes that the phone's screen does not display anything, but the touch input still works.*

1. Figure out how to take a screenshot on your phone without using the UI. On the Galaxy S4, you can use hardware buttons to do this.
2. Unlock your phone's lock screen, and connect it to a computer.
3. Open the phone in a file manager.
4. Find the location where the phone stores screenshots.
5. Take a screenshot on the phone. Look at the updated screenshot.

By doing this, you can perform an action on Android, take a screenshot, and see what screen comes up. After doing this awhile, you should be able to find the USB Debugging menu.

Comment: HA! Clever one! The case is gone for a long time now but definitively +1 for creativity!

Comment: it worked for me, finally ! you could kiss you, sir

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use a new phone say an S4 to your cracked broken S4 and get to the video port (several youtube videos on this) hook the new screen to the old phone and now you have access to debug set usb or transfer all the files its just as simple as plugging in a working screen!